# RewriteRule and 301 on url without trailing slash at the end

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a new web site that needs to 301 old pages and also add vanity url on some path

new website product page example url 
http://www.mywebsite.com/en/section/nice-url-name_123.html 
from this url i need to grab the section, name and id

this is my rule

```
RewriteRule ^en/([^_]+)/([^_]+)_([0-9]+).html /en/$1/detail.php?name=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

this works fine

on previous version of the website they used this url format

http://www.mywebsite.com/en/section/nice-url-name

I can't find a way to intercept this url and redirect to my new URL, id is missing and can be 0

so it should become
http://www.mywebsite.com/en/section/nice-url-name_0.html

since i could't find a way i try adding a trailling slash at URL

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|png|gif|ttf|ttf)$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

and then try to catch them section by section

```
RewriteRule ^en/section1/([^_]+)/ /it/301.php?redirectd=section1&name=$1 [L]
```

I couldn't find any other way without ending in infinite 301 loop
But this way I need to exclude all my extension otherwise Apache will add trailing slash at the end of image, font, pdf and so on

Comment: Why `([^_]+)` everywhere? Doesn't `([^/]+)` make much more sense for the section?

Comment: And why can't you match `/en/section/nice-url-name`? Seems pretty straight forward to me, no double rewriting required.

Comment: could you provide me an example?

Comment: Probably something like that, I'd say: `RewriteRule ^/?en/([^/]+)/([^\./]+)$ /en/301.php?redirected=1&section=$1&name=$2 [L]`

Comment: thanks it seems to work i also changed other rule with ([^/]+) instead ([^_]+) you can answer and i will accept

Comment: Sure, as you like. Glad I could be of service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your statement "I can't find a way to intercept this url ..." I would like to suggest something along these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?en/([^/]+)/([^\./]+)$ /en/301.php?redirected=1&section=$1&name=$2 [L]
```